# Use before_destroy to delete another model's entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, destroy

So I have a model, let's call it Notes. On the notes, you can but several posts. So the notes model has the line:

```
 has_many :posts
```

And the posts model has the line

```
 belongs_to :note
```

Now, when a User destroys a post, I want for the note to be destroyed IF it not longer has any other posts.

I thought i would write this code into the post model with before_destroy:

```
 def delete_note_if_last_post
    if self.note.posts.count == 1
      self.note.destroy
    end
  end
```

This doesn't work. It shuts down the server based on an "Illegal Instruction". Is there some way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

EDIT: changed the code, as I noticed an error, and now the problem is slightly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can return false to prevent a model from destruction in before_destroy filter

```
before_destroy :has_no_post
```

then in has_no_post

```
def has_no_post
 #You can prevent this from deletion by using these options
 #Option1 return false on certain condition  
return false if posts.any?

#or add an error to errors
errors << "Can not delete note if it has post" if posts.any?
#raise an exception 
raise "Cant delete ..." if blah blah
```

end

Comment: Naveed i think you meant raise "Cant delete ..." instead of rails "Cant delete ..."

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting this kind of logic into an observer. Something like

```
class PostObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_destroy(post)
    note = Note.find(post.note_id)
    note.destroy if note.posts.count == 0
  end
end
```

You'd have to register the observer in your config/application.rb file as well. One thing to note is that if your callback returns any value that can be evaluated as false (e.g. nil or false) the rest of your callbacks will not run.

Comment: Also, the actual error would be helpful. It may be that your code works, but something else is causing the 'Illegal Instruction' error.